# Can spread operator (...) be applied to object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the reducers/todos.js section of redux document (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html):

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        completed: !state.completed
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

the `state` here is an object, I think the '`...`' operator can't be applied on object but only on array, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the redux example seems to use an experimental babel plugin based on an ES8 proposal.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, the code doesn't compile yet.